How can I set a numeric wildcard in MySQL?
I'm trying to create a SQL script that finds codes in two different databases. I want to set a parameter that has a numeric wildcard.
Codes are often written like this for example, ABC108, ABC109, DEF47213, etc. I set the parameter as ABC[0-9]+ to return all possible variations of codes that start with ABC, but that resulted in a blank output.
I tried the following, expecting the most recent code made in both databases to be outputted:
SET @investment_code = 'ABC[0-9]+';

SELECT 
    investment_name, 
    i.service_client_id, 
    currency_symbol, 
    investment_code C_investment_codes
FROM client.investments i
LEFT JOIN client.currencies c
    ON i.currency_id = c.id
WHERE i.investment_code COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci LIKE @investment_code
ORDER BY investment_code DESC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT 
`key`, 
service_client_id, 
`value` SD_investment_codes
FROM client_data.standing_data sd
WHERE sd.`value` COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci LIKE @investment_code
ORDER BY `value` DESC
LIMIT 1;

This resulted in a blank output. When I use SET @investment_code = 'ABC%'; I get results, but I specifically want to set the parameter for digits to follow ABC. This is my expected output:



C_investment_codes
SD_investment_codes




ABC109
ABC109




In MySQL, the LIKE operator does not support regular expressions directly. Instead, you can use the % wildcard to match any sequence of characters.
For your script, you can leverage the REGEXP operator available in MySQL, which allows you to use regular expressions. Here's an example
SET @investment_code = '^ABC[0-9]+$';

SELECT 
    investment_name, 
    i.service_client_id, 
    currency_symbol, 
    investment_code AS C_investment_codes
FROM client.investments i
LEFT JOIN client.currencies c
    ON i.currency_id = c.id
WHERE i.investment_code REGEXP @investment_code
ORDER BY investment_code DESC
LIMIT 1;

table
SELECT 
    `key`, 
    service_client_id, 
    `value` AS SD_investment_codes
FROM client_data.standing_data sd
WHERE sd.`value` REGEXP @investment_code
ORDER BY `value` DESC
LIMIT 1;


Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow

That's cool. My response is way too short and rough to be a ChatGPT response however.

This worked! Thank you. I tried using the REGEXP @investment_code with my original parameter, but it still resulted in a blank output. Added the '$' after the '^ABC[0-9]+' now after reading your comment and it works!

You can try REGEXP operator instead of LIKE.
REGEXP 'ABC[0-9]'

